# Как обновить блок при использовании routes

Tags: php, ajax

Как произвести обновление блока `div` по его ID при условии, что все страницы подключены к одному исполняющему файлу `index.php`? Страницы расположены в папке `/pages/`.

Использую код

```
<script>  
    $("#refresh-btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#block-refresh").load('index.php');
    });  
</script>
```

Но он не хочет работать, меняю вместо **index.php** ставлю прямую ссылку до файла **/pages/products.php** он вызывает долгожданное обновление, но он попросту удаляет что внутри обновляемого блока и не дает исполнится коду php внутри этого блока.

Нужно произвести обновление без перезагрузки страницы — кнопкой обновить список товаров.

Comment: Где у Вас код ajax-запроса?

Comment: @Coder в /pages/products.php он обновляет, но он просто обновляет и удаляет все что внутри блока. в index.php он вовсе не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы говорите об ajax, так будьте-любезны использовать ajax.
Попробую навести вас на верный ход мыслей.
Вот у нас index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="refresh">
    //тут у нас код. обращаемся в базу и делаем то что нам надо.
  </div>

  <a href="#" id="refreshBtn">
    <span class="button">Обновить</span>
  </a>
</body>

<script>
  function funcBefore () {
      $("#refresh").text ("Ожидаю данные...");
  }

  function funcSuccess (data) {
      $("#refresh").html(data);
  }

  $(document).ready(function)(){
    // обработчик кнопки
    $("#refreshBtn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax ({
            url: "script.php ",
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: funcBefore,
            success: funcSuccess
        });
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

А вот у нас ответ скрипта script.php

```
<?php
//инклудим скрипт для соединения с базой.
//обращаемся в базу. и вытаскиваем инфу.
//далее выводим полученный результат.
echo "Результат обращения в базу";
?>
```

Алсо.
Не имеет значения что у вас там в `<div id="refresh">` . Пусть там `_include`, не важно. Работать должно.
Если не работает - дебажим код по логам и выводу в консоле.

PS.
передача переменных ajaxом.

```
$(document).ready(function)(){
        // обработчик кнопки
        $("#refreshBtn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           //записываем переменную для передачи ajax
           var id= "<?php echo $id;?>";
            $.ajax ({
                type:"POST",
                url: "script.php ",
                 data: {"id":id
                            },
                beforeSend: funcBefore,
                success: funcSuccess
            });
        });
      });
```

В скрипте тогда ловить будем его так `$_POST['id'];`

Comment: Проблема не в коде, а в том что при обновлении в блок `<div "block-refresh">` добавляется весь код страницы. но не выполняется обновление php кода внутри `<div "block-refresh">` php-код выводит из базы список товаров. Мне надо это обновлять при нажатии на кнопку без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Ваш код и мой выше отлично работает в index.php он обновляет все как надо, но вот беда он не работает там где нужно. в index.php идет подключение страниц и в зависимости от routes[] подключается инклюд страницы

Comment: routes? Вы используете какой-то фрэймворк?

да и какая разница впринципе.....
Если у вас подгружается в `div ` который надо, код который надо - то в чем проблема, не пойму?

Comment: Нет, обычный роутер для php. класс который разбивает ссылку на маршруты example.com/one/two/free index.php подключает страницы через include в зависимости от маршрута.

Comment: так. Где находиться `<div "block-refresh">` ? и где находится контент который вы хотите добавить в этот блок?

Comment: `<div "block-refresh">` находится в `/pages/products.php` контент находится в этом блоке `<div "block-refresh">`

Comment: Что должно произойти, когда вы нажмете на кнопку refresh?

Comment: При обычном обновление страницы на `F5` идет выгрузка информации из базы данных. Мне надо при нажатии на кнопку сделать тоже самое но только с конкретным блоком, обновить его т.е вызвать php код который выполнит загрузку товаров, но без обновления самой страницы.

Comment: Я дал вам рабочий пример кода. Вам его надо переделать под вашу задачу.

Comment: Я не знаю как его переделать не особо разбираюсь в аякс.

Comment: например - можно сделать отдельный скрипт script.php. Который будет делать то же самое, что и код внутри вашего div. А при нажатии на кнопку обновления, заменять содержимое div, выводом из этого скрипта. В ajax-запросе надо поменять url  на путь до этого скипта. Ну и подумать где и как его расположить

Comment: создал для примера файл в корне test.php с содержимым `echo time();` при нажатии на выводит Ожидаю данные... и дальше ничего не происходит

Comment: Файл может лежать где угодно. Посмотреть лог-файл? Посмотреть Fiddlerom, или в Хроме, возвращается ли test.php? Что падает в консоль?

Comment: Я поправил свой ответ, дополнил его кодом. Может быть, так у нас получится? =)

Comment: Спасибо, но а как в данном случае через ajax  в script.php мне узнать id категории который расположен в главном файле? ид находится в переменной php $catid которая присваивается из роутера в главном файле. Я понимаю что его нужно передать через ajax (но я в нем не разбираюсь)

Comment: Дополнил, как это сделать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Николай) Буду учить мат.часть.